# How to set token expiration time when using django-rest-authtoken?

Tags: django, django-rest-auth

I'm using the django-rest-authtoken library (https://github.com/wichmannpas/django-rest-authtoken) to manage my API users.
The biggest inconvenience is that the user authentication tokens expire in 24 hours, effectively requiring to perform login every day.
Unfortunately I couldn't find a way to change the token expiration time.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like 1 day is default value in settings:

https://github.com/wichmannpas/django-rest-authtoken/blob/master/rest_authtoken/settings.py#L10

so setting `AUTH_TOKEN_VALIDITY` in your project should do the job.

Comment: Thanks, should have looked in the settings file, which I admittedly hadn't done. I'm sure it will work, but will report back anyways.